# Reconfigure standard Mac OS X FTP server to run on another port

Tags: mac, ftp, port

How to reconfigure standard Mac OS X FTP server to run on another port? For example 2021 instead of 21?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the man page, you need to change the port number in /etc/services from 21 to 2021.

Once you've made the change, just stop/start the service in System Preferences.

Comment: You may also need to  to restart the ftp daemon for it to take effect :
In Terminal --> run 
"launchctl stop com.apple.ftpd"   ** then run **
 "launchctl start com.apple.ftpd"

Comment: launchctl stop com.apple.ftpd does not work.
You need to do a: launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist and then a launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist to stop/start the FTP (at least in OS X 10.12). (the 1st is "unload" & the 2nd is "load")